# How to set an input (text) value to a PHP variable on the fly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Basically I'm using datepicker from jQuery to have my client pick a date. I then want to take that date (once they select it) and process it through the DB to pre-fill a timepicker.

Problem is, I don't know how to take the value of that input box and process it without actually having to submit a form. I want to deal with the value once they choose.

Here is my datepicker code:

`$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" )
            .datepicker({ minDate: '+1' });
    });`

I guess I would somehow have to add an onblur event, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this is.

Comment: AJAX.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually have the server process the value of the date picker without submitting a form you would have to pass that value to the server via AJAX.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       $.ajax({
          url: "yourscript.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: ({date : dateText}),
          success: function(data){
             alert(data); 
          }
       }); 
   }
});
```

Comment: I had to change the url and data to this for it to work but it works, the URL points to a controller function: onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $.ajax({
      url: "/order/get_preorder_time/",
      type: "POST",
      data: "date="+dateText,
      success: function(data){
      var endTime = data; 
      document.write(endTime);
      }
       }); 
      }

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the JQuery [AJAX support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").change(function(){
$.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url :"URL here",
   Success:function(responsed){ alert("added"); }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use ajax for this if you don't want a form sent.

```
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    // code for IE6, IE5
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }       
    xmlhttp.open("GET",site,false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Where the var `site` is the php page with get vars attached, or if you have to use a POST request change `"GET"` to `"POST"` and replace the `null` in `xmlhttp.send(null)` with a string of post vars.

Hope this helped!